# Using Cassandra sstableloader from one AWS instance to another, fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

One AWS instance has Cassandra (2.1.16) installed and running. Another AWS instance does not have Cassandra installed, but is using the sstableloader program found in the apache-cassandra-2.1.16 binary. The cassandra.yaml used on the sstableloader server has the following settings:

cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
listen_address: 
storage_port: 7000
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160

Both servers are using the same AWS security group which has the following ports open to the group:

7000, 9160

When I execute ssltableloader like this:

```
./sstableloader -d <CassandraNode> -f ../../cassandra/cassandra.yaml -v ../../cassandra/<Keyspace>/<CFName>/
```

I get this error:

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of ../../cassandra/<Keyspace>/<CFName>/<Keyspace-CFName>-ka-6952-Data.db ../../cassandra/<Keyspace>/<CFName>/<Keyspace-CFName>-ka-6951-Data.db to [/public ip of Cassandra node]
ERROR 20:06:33 [Stream #c7915b50-f7a7-11e6-bd84-8dd23712cb6e] Streaming error occurred
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.createConnection(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.createConnection(StreamSession.java:240) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.initiate(ConnectionHandler.java:80) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:227) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:208) [apache-cassandra-2.1.16.jar:2.1.16]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
progress: total: 100% 0  MB/s(avg: 0 MB/s)WARN  20:06:33 [Stream #c7915b50-f7a7-11e6-bd84-8dd23712cb6e] Stream failed
Streaming to the following hosts failed:
[/<public ip of Cassandra node>]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:125)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:209)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:185)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:413)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:518)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:233)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have successfully used sstableloader from my local pc to load data into the Cassandra node on AWS. Where I'm failing is when I try to sstableloader from one ASW instance to another.

For full disclosure, I've also tried this with all ports open between the 2 instances and it results in the same failure.

Is there a configuration step that I'm missing on the instance trying to do the sstableloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cassandra node was using its public ip as its broadcast_address. This worked when I used sstableloader from my box. It failed when trying to use sstableloader from another AWS instance, since that server could not find the Cassandra node via its public IP. I was able to make it work by using the Cassandra node's private IP as the broadcast_address.